# Python: How to handle try/except faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently in my project, I’m handling exceptions:

```
try:
   …
   # Run code 1
except:
   …
   # Run code 2
```

But when an error occurs which my `except` handles — the error is common and expected, it takes awhile for it to recognize the error to handle an exception and execute `code 2`. 
Is there any way for the program to recognize the error faster to handle the exception quicker?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to vote up/accept answer

Comment: If the error is common and expected, it’s not an **exception**, so you shouldn’t have it throw an exception.

Comment: Providing more context around exactly what is happening around that exception, e.g. is it a `ValueError` you're catching, or some custom exception, would be useful.

Comment: AFAICT, Only by knowing the code that throws the exception could one find out what could be done better.

Comment: A `try: ... except: ...` construct isn't (noticeably) slow. If you're having performance issues, it's most likely your code that's at fault.

Comment: "it takes awhile for it to recognize the error" - have you actually timed that? If so, how? Are you sure this part of the process is actually what's making your code slow?

Comment: @not_a_robot Please take a look at the original post. Just made an edit.

Comment: @Rawing But would there be a faster way to execute the `except`?

Comment: @user2357112 Seeing if it can be optimized. Added full code in original post.

Comment: @poke Appreciate your response. Any better alternatives? Made an edit with the actual code in the original post.

Comment: Well, it’s apparently not the exception throwing that makes your code slow (which was to be expected) but the actual code that runs. In order to check whether something does not exist, the crawler will have to look at *everything* and that’s bound to take some time. If that’s really taking that long, maybe you should just look for all `<option>` elements directly and then check for `red` and `blue` once you have that?

Comment: @poke Appreciate the insight! That's exactly the type of advice I was seeking for, optimization. `.find_option_by_text()` is in fact check checking for all `options` though. Could you elaborate on what you mean by look for all `<option>` elements directly?

Comment: I don’t know this library, but maybe you can use the `find_by_tag` function and then once you have all option elements, you check [their text](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.ElementAPI.text) manually by looping only through them once.

Comment: @poke Did actually give it a try, but it returns `[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x104e968d0>]`. Shouldn't it be returning a list?

Comment: That is a list, a list with one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s apparent that the code to find the [option by text](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_option_by_text) is the thing that is the slow part about your code. This isn’t too surprising since it has to look at the whole document to get to the result, that there is not a single element with the queried text.

So what is slowing your code down is that you have to look at the document twice to find an option with either text. What you could try is looking at the document just once by finding *all* option elements and then looking for those texts yourself. I don’t know this library, but I guess that you can use [`find_by_tag`](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_tag) for this. This should give you a [list](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/element-list.html#splinter.element_list.ElementList) you can iterate and then you can look at each element’s [`text`](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.ElementAPI.text) to check against `'red'` and `'blue'`.

In order to ensure that you prioritize options with the text `'red'` over those with `'blue'`, you will have to look at all elements in the list. You cannot stop just because you found any of those colors, otherwise a blue one may be found although a red one appears later in the document. So you need to remember blue matches until you find a red element (in which case that one wins), or you hit the end of the document.

This could look like this (completely speculated and untested):

```
def getRedOrBlueOption(browser):
    blueOption = None
    for option in browser.find_by_tag('option'):
        # if we find a red one, we’re already done
        if option.text() == 'red':
            return option

        # if we find a blue one, and we didn’t already find another one,
        # remember that for later.
        elif option.text() == 'blue' and not blueOption:
            blueOption = option

        # otherwise, just keep looking

    # After looking at the last option, if we’re here, we didn’t find
    # a red option. However, we could have found a blue one. If that’s
    # the case, `blueOption` will contain that option. If we didn’t find
    # either of those options, `blueOption` will be still `None` which
    # we could either return to signalize that we didn’t find anything, or
    # throw an exception

    # if blueOption is None:
    #     raise ValueError('Red or blue option not found')

    return blueOption
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your response. Worked beautifully